# Почему скрипт падает в бесконечную рекурсию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть маленький код на jQuery
Он слушает событие изменение класса у #test и если клас был изменен пытается проверить что был добавлен js-header-change-moment у него, если да то к элементу #nav-submenu-1 добавляется класс 
Но при работе он говорит: too much recursion 
Где тут рекурсия и почему не пойму?

```
(function(){
        var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;
        $.fn.addClass = function(){
            var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            $(this).trigger('cssClassChanged');
            return result;
        }
    })();
    $(function(){
        $("#test").bind('cssClassChanged', function(){
            if($("#test").hasClass("js-header-change-moment")){
                console.log('true');
                $('#nav-submenu-1').addClass('cs-sub-menu-home-dow');
            }else{
                console.log('false');
                $("#nav-submenu-1").removeClass('cs-sub-menu-home-dow');
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: у вас добавляется класс, на это срабатывает байндинг и класс удаляется, на это сробатывает байндинг и класс добавляется, на это сробатывает байндинг и класс удаляется и т.д. :)

Comment: А как сделать что бы он добавлял удалял только когда появляется определенный класс у элемента? что бы когда у эелмента #test появляется класс js-header-change-moment в #nav-submenu-1 добавлялся cs-sub-menu-home-dow

Comment: Все само поченилось

Answer (score 0):

У вас добавляется класс, на это срабатывает байндинг и класс удаляется, на это сробатывает байндинг и класс добавляется, на это сробатывает байндинг и класс удаляется и т.д. :)
Надо что-то вроде такого:

```
$(function(){
   $("#test").bind('cssClassChanged', function(){
       if($("#test").hasClass("js-header-change-moment") && $("#test").hasClass('cs-sub-menu-home-dow') === false)
       {
            console.log('true');
            $('#nav-submenu-1').addClass('cs-sub-menu-home-dow');
       }
       else if($("#test").hasClass("js-header-change-moment") === false && $("#test").hasClass('cs-sub-menu-home-dow') === true)
       {
            console.log('false');
            $("#nav-submenu-1").removeClass('cs-sub-menu-home-dow');
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще одно решение которое было предложено моим коллегой 
Вполне себе рабочие

```
(function(){
    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;
    $.fn.addClass = function(){
        var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply(this, arguments);
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'test') {
            $(this).trigger('cssClassChanged');
        }
        return result;
    }
})();
$(function(){
    $("#test").bind('cssClassChanged', function(){
        if($("#test").hasClass("js-header-change-moment")){
            $('#nav-submenu-1').addClass('cs-sub-menu-home-dow');
        }else{
            $("#nav-submenu-1").removeClass('cs-sub-menu-home-dow');
        }

    });
});
```